# What does Islam say about Jihad?

Tags: jihad

As far as I knew, according to Islam, the word “Jihad” means “to struggle.” There are two types of “Jihad”:

1. Greater Jihad (“Jihad al-Akbar”): This refers to the struggle to improve oneself spiritually, to practice Islam faithfully, to overcome one's own baser instincts, and to live in accordance with Islamic principles.

   - This concept of Jihad emphasizes self-control, personal growth, and spiritual development.
2. Lesser Jihad (“Jihad al-Asghar”): This refers to the external struggle against oppression and injustice, which can include the defense of Muslims and Islam if they are under attack. It is sometimes associated with the concept of armed struggle or warfare, but it is important to note that there are strict rules governing such warfare in Islamic law.

   - The conduct of lesser Jihad must be in accordance with Islamic principles of justice and ethics and not for aggression or personal gain.

Someone told me that these definitions are based on *Dhaif* hadiths. I.e., in other words, Islam doesn't have a clear definition of the term "Jihad."

If so, what should be correct definition of the term "Jihad?"

Comment: These are covered on existing answers under the jihad tag. For example see my answer on: https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1360