# Is seeking blessing from parents shirk?

Tags: shirk

I used to go to my parents and ask them to bless me. Then, they would put their hands on my head and say, "May god bless you". My question is whether that was shirk.

Comment: Maybe we should begin with the [definition of shirk](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/516/17163).

Comment: I will do taubah and will never think that anyone can bless me except Allah am i right or wrong thanks for help sister

Comment: "And whatever you have of blessings - it is from Allah" - Qur'an 16:53. All blessings are from Allah. You can ask your parents to pray for you but it is not them blessing you but Allah.

Comment: In case of parents who themselves are non-Muslims that certainly would at least feel like shirk! I guess your post lacks some details ...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The blessings from parent if in the from of prayer asking almighty Allah to bless you, there is no problem with that and every Muslim should have that habbit of seeking such blessings from his parents.

Comment: This doesn't look like an answer as we expect here, but like a comment. We require answers to be well elaborated, focused on asnwering the actual question and claims to be supported by evidences (see [answer]).