# Did I commit shirk..?

Tags: sin, forgiveness

I am 13 years old, and a girl. I decided to come here, feeling the need for an answer because I'm greatly afraid of the fires or hell.

Ever since I learned about shirk, I started to receive heinous thoughts such as, 'I worship Aphrodite along with Allah' and 'There are other gods along with Allah' but I never truly mean them. I once said out loud to myself, 'I would worship Lakshmi, the goddess of wealth, but I am a muslim, so I only worship Allah' and I once said 'I worship Aphrodite along with Allah' but I never meant it. By Allah I did not mean to think, or even say any of these things. When I had realised about what I had said, I was sent into a wave of panic, and worry.

Whenever I talk to Allah in my mind, I always whisper, 'A'uthu Billahi mina shaytanir rajeem, Allah, I apologise for my terrible thoughts. I really hope i haven't committed shirk.'

I started to cry and I would always imagine my mother going to heaven and seeing myself in hell and I start to cry all the time. I am too afraid to tell my mom about this because I feel like she would be angry at me.
Will Allah still forgive me, or am I doomed?

Comment: "Ever since I learned about shirk, I started to receive heinous thoughts such as, 'I worship Aphrodite along with Allah'" are you a Greek (do you live in Greek).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is shirk in Islam?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/516/what-is-shirk-in-islam)

Answer (score 1):

You are 13 years old. I know from myself and from my children that 13 years old is a very difficult age: You have lost the innocence of a child who has a free fantasy and listens to the parents and other adults to tell them what to do and what not to do. You are completely new to becoming a grown-up, reflecting on your own with your own conciousness. Still you are thinking of your mum - here or observing you from heaven, you being in hell - and you will still need her spoken or felt advice for some more years.

I do not know where your thoughts on Aphrodite and Lakshmi come from. Aphrodite can only come from books or films as nobody in present is worshipping the old Greek deities; with Lakshmi it may be the same unless you are living in India. From wherever these figures have come into your mind, they are still a remains of childhood-like fantasy. You are already aware that they are not real, and you are aware that it is shirk to worship them.

God knows you. Do not be too afraid of Him; He knows what age you have and that you do not seriously set those figures as deities at His side. Do not be afraid of your phantasy but just put them in their right place, that is, they are fiction and phantasy, nothing more.

God will be your guidance, and He will guide you if you want.

Comment: You shouldn't have typed "do not be too afraid of Him". What do you mean by it?

Comment: @Afiq Fear hinders faith, trust and love. Is it not God our Protector Who cares for us, Who is the source of all material and immaterial? Those who fear God only avoid what is forbidden (haram), one who goes with God also seeks to do good (mubah)

Answer (score 0):

i saw this kind of question before on quora and the answer was that the devil is putting these thoughts in your mind if you are walking the straight path to your master dont let a dog barking distract you from walking the straight path if you do that than you will be late to meet your master just ignore the barking and move on .
that was the answer that i remember i hope this helps and Allah knows best.