# Am I commiting shirk if I sing the Indian National anthem?

Tags: shirk

Does the Indian National anthem contain any lines of shirk?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is shirk in Islam?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/516/what-is-shirk-in-islam)

Comment: Can you file the text of it in English?

Comment: Not everyone on this forum is Indian or understands Hindi (I assume that is the language of your anthem) .. if you could post the English translation here, it would help us analyze what you are referring to.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you believe the content of national anthem to be true from the heart. No, if you disbelieve the content at heart but just utter it for the sake of it. Then there is no problem in it. But it is better to avoid because the below statement which dilutes monotheism and brings in a partner who is capable of controlling the destiny. And this is shirk in Ruboobiyyah(Lordship). According to Islamic creed destiny is controlled only by the Creator Allah. He ordains both Good and Evil to test mankind.

> Thou art the ruler of the minds of all people, dispenser of India's
> destiny

.