# Did I commit Shirk for playing this game?

Tags: halal-haram, sharia, shirk, tawba, jahannam

A few years ago my brother introduced me to a game that I played a lot. This game was based on Greek mythology and in it there was a character (which you play as) which was considered a god astaġfiru -llāhᵃ. I was explaining to my brother something and I called him a god (astaġfiru -llāhᵃ). I don't remember if I said "in Greek mythology". I was really young back then and did not even know the word shirk and had no concept of it. This question just dawned on me a week ago.  Also I never thought of him as a real god (astaġfiru -llāhᵃ). Did I commit shirk? Please if there is any hadith or Ayaat of shirk being forgiven please tell me in your answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will Allah forgive me for doing X ? (reference question)](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/71337/will-allah-forgive-me-for-doing-x-reference-question)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is shirk in Islam?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/516/what-is-shirk-in-islam)

Answer (score -1):

playing this sort of game is sinful, but since you were young and ignorant you are pardoned so long as you don't play such a game in the future and repent from  any previous sins regardless.